# DHCP through VPN not working

Tags: vpn, dhcp

Fair warning: This will be a long post because the issue is quite tangled and I am not really proficient with network setups. Here goes:

I have a location where I have recently ungraded the former DSL internet that was very slow to 4G. The ISP (Orange Mobile) gave me a Huawei router that is quite basic and immediately I ran into an issue. At this location I have a DVR with some cameras I need to monitor and a server for home automation (Home Assistant running in a virtual machine). In order for me to monitor the cameras and access the server I needed to port forward some ports. This was the first issue, the router they gave me had no way to port forward any ports. After some digging I found out that I have to use a second router connected to the Huawei and set the Huawei in bridge mode. So in very crude terms Huawei received the 4G signal and passes it on to the second router (a Netgear WNDR3700v2, running dd-wrt).

I thought that this solved my problem but I was wrong. Apparently there is a trend among ISPs now (at least in my country) that the public ip (which is dynamically allocated) that is seen by the router is different than the one seen by a device behind the router. So in my case in the router status windows there is a WAN IP which is different that what I obtain by going to whatismyip.com. This creates a huge problem because I cannot use DDNS services or scripts to keep the dynamic IP updated to a domain I own.

Doing more digging I found out that a solution to this situation would be to setup a VPN. So I have decided to set the router I have at home as a VPN server and the Netgear router at that location as a client.

Let me call the home router RH (router-home) and the netgear router RL (router-location).

VPN Settings are as follows:

RH (Asus Merlin):

```
Interface Type: TAP

Protocol: UDP

Allocate from DHCP: Yes

Advertise DNS to clients: Yes

rest are security related settings that do not seem to be the problem
```

RL (Netgear, dd-wrt):

```
DHCP server turned off and set the LAN router IP to a value from my home network: 192.168.1.xxx

Tunnel device is: TAP

NAT is Disabled

Bridge TAP to br0: Enabled
```

This setup works partially as follows:

I have given the DVR and the server (with the VMs) static IPs from my home network: 192.168.1.xx1 , 192.168.1.xx2 etc. and they can all connect to the internet without a problem. I can access them from anywhere through my network by forwarding the required ports on my RH.

What doesn't work is anything else that is connected to RL. If I connect a mobile phone to RL and let it receive an IP via the DHCP server from RH, I get no internet connection. The IP is given but what appears to happen is that there is no gateway setting that is given to the new device connected to RL through the DHCP server at RH.

I feel that I am missing something simple yet crucial for this to work and I can't put my finger on it.

Can anyone help me out with this? If this setup works, then I plan to set RH to increase its DHCP pool to span 192.168.0.xxx and 192.168.1.xxx and hopefully somehow (don't know how yet, but one problem at a time!) give my home devices ips from the 0 class and the other location ips from 1 class.

Also, is there a better way to approach this problem?

Edit:
As @someuser mentioned in a comment, I didn't explain what I wanted to achieve in the end. The goal is to allow devices connected to RL access to the internet as well. I have achieved my primary goal with accessing the DVR and the home automation server from anywhere. But with this setup, any other device that connects to RL and receives an IP via DHCP will not have internet access. The received IP is from RH network and I can ping it from home like it was on my network.

The devices that connect to RL can be mobile phones, an occasional laptop, and ESP32, ESP8266 and raspberry pi devices for home automation.

Obviously I would love to have the RL network separate (except for the DVR and server going through the VPN), with the clients receiving DHCP IPs from RL and still being able to communicate to the home automation server. Sorry if this is still not clear. I don't know all the proper terms.

Comment: Just to explain your initial challenge. Your 4G provider is most likely assigning your 4G router a private and short-lived IP and then NAT'ing your traffic along with other wireless customer. So even if you know the public IP (DDNS can actually do this without problem), you won't be able to port forward into your LAN because your wireless carrier simply will not allow it. You made the right choice of using VPN. However, I am not clear is what you want to do with your 2nd problem. Do you want your mobile device connected to RL to have just internet access or you want to access it through VPN?

Comment: What I wanted to do I accomplished, i.e.: access the DVR and the automation server. The problem is that when I am at the RL location, any device (I used a mobile phone as an example) that connects to the Netgear router, doesn't have internet access, but it receives an IP from RH. I know that because I can ping the IP from RH. So yes I would like devices to have internet. i don't mind it if they go through the VPN. I will edit my post a bit to explain it better.

Comment: I assume you have no problem accessing your DVR through your VPN? Does your DVR has internet access then? My guess is it does not. If your device getting an IP from RH, most likely its default gateway is also RH. Which means you need to setup your RH to translated the traffic to the Internet. There are potentially other way to solve this problem though. For example, your RH can assigning IP to your DVR but having your RL assign the IP and either setup static routes on RH and RL or make RL perform port forwarding to the DVRs.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. I can now access the DVR from the internet because I have assigned a FIXED ip to it and it is in the same class as RH. Then on RH i port forward the necessary ports and I can access it from anywhere THROUGH RH. But as I said the dvr is not the issue. The issue is with other devices (phone, laptop etc) connected to RL that will receive an IP from RH but not a gateway. So no internet access for them. Is this possible to do through a VPN?